# App runs on few emulators but crashes on real device

Tags: java, android

i am working on a calculator app. The app runs on few emulators but not on real device. There are alot of errors in logcat. I am confused how to solve these errors.

```
2021-12-20 21:02:39.726 9164-9164/? E/hmad.calculato: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-12-20 21:02:40.530 9164-9164/com.ahmad.calculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ahmad.calculator, PID: 9164
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Linear gradient requires 'angle' attribute to be a multiple of 45
        at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable$GradientState.updateGradientStateOrientation(GradientDrawable.java:2255)
        at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable$GradientState.getOrientation(GradientDrawable.java:2243)
        at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.ensureValidRect(GradientDrawable.java:1307)
        at android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable.draw(GradientDrawable.java:725)
        at android.view.View.getDrawableRenderNode(View.java:22113)
        at android.view.View.drawBackground(View.java:22047)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21800)
        at android.widget.Switch.draw(Switch.java:1299)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20642)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21525)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4542)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4279)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20633)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21525)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4542)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4279)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20633)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21525)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4542)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4279)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:1994)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21820)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20642)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21525)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4542)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4279)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20633)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21525)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4542)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4279)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20633)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21525)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4542)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4279)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20633)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21525)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4542)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4279)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20633)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21525)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4542)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4279)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21820)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:869)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:20642)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:575)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:581)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:654)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:4126)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3914)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2051)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8456)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1065)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:889)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:816)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1050)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7830)
2021-12-20 21:02:40.530 9164-9164/com.ahmad.calculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1040)
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the Android documentation:

> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable
>
> **android:angle**
>
> Angle of the gradient, used only with linear gradient. Must be a
> multiple of 45 in the range [0, 315].
>
> May be a floating point value, such as "1.2".

It might be worthwhile to compare the Android versions on your emulators vs. your handset.

In any case, a linear gradient that's not a multiple of 45 is definitely a "bug", regardless if the app happens to actually crash or not.